# How to format this datatables export to excel?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable where I am exporting the results in excel spreadsheet. Most of the rows have long text along with some formatting such as line breaks, lists.

Is there a way to do the following when exporting to excel?

1. Wrap text for all the cells
2. Preserve line breaks, p and ul tags.

Here is my example: https://live.datatables.net/yamifera/1/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searching: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      target: 6,
      visible: false,
      searchable: true,
    }],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible'
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        orientation: 'landscape',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible'
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'print',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible'
        }
      },
      //  'colvis'
    ],
  });

  buildSelect(table);

  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value="">select me</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // ** MY CHANGE **
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>
<div class="searchbox">
  <p>Name:
    <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
  </p>
  <p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
  </p>
  <p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
<table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Hidden Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><a href="Test1">AALorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
  <ul>
    <li>
      dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
    <li>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</li>
  </ul>
  it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<p><a  href="Test2"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
              <p><a href="Test3">qsdfdfdgffg</a></p>
      </td>
      <td>AALorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
      <td>Sys Architect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett -2</td>
      <td>
        <p>Director: fgghghjhjhjhkjkj
          <p>
      </td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
      <td>Director:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
      <td>
        <p>Technical Authorjkjkjk fdfd h gjjjhjhk
          <p>
      </td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
      <td>Tech author</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: ummm `</head>
<div class="searchbox">` do you see the issue there?

Comment: I formatted your code so you could see some issues easier in the posted sample

Comment: The `exportOptions` option supports a `format` option. This gives you access to the `innerHtml` - as in `body: function ( innerHtml, rowIdx, colIdx, node ) { ... }`. In that function you can convert the relevant HTML tags to whatever text attributes you need - such as newlines, and whatever character to use as a bullet point. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68765820/12567365) - different objectives but uses the `innerHtml` approach.

Comment: The above approach is OK for plain text changes - but for formatting such as wrapping text in Excel cells (and maybe setting column widths) - that is [much more involved](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41778). It requires you to manipulate Excel's underlying XML structures using the DataTables `customize: function( xlsx )`. I would focus on one question at a time (since they are very different issues).

Comment: Thankyou. I figured out how to wrap text but I am not able to figure out how to format <p>tags and <br> tags. Is it possible for you to provide jsfiddle?